# ASP.NET cannot read file: "access to the path ... is denied"

Tags: asp.net, file-permissions

**tl;dr: critical bits are in bold.**

We have a website page that, when executed, is supposed to read in a series of files, zip them up, and return them to the user.

Unfortunately, we are running into an error:

> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.

My line attempting to access the file currently looks like this:

```
using (FileStream x = File.Open(@"\\thedirectory\filename.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) { }
```

(This line doesn't do anything useful other than try to open the file, since right now I'm just trying to see if I have access at all.)

**This code works, and opens the file without a problem if I copy the file to a directory on my machine and have the path go there.  But if I go to the remote machine where the original file is, no dice.**

I went down a rabbit hole for a while trying to make sure that whoever the ASP.NET process was running as, that process had permissions to the directory.  However, since that wasn't working and I was getting desperate, **I have given "everyone" all access rights to the remote directory as a test.  Still getting the same error.**

I'm guessing this is a permissions issue (since that's what it's claiming) combined with the fact that the code works when pointing at a local file.  However, **since I've already given "everyone" all permissions, I'm lost as to what could be going wrong.**

Ideas?

Comment: Are you testing this in your LocalHost? If you are it seems like an ASPNET user account issue. Try and see if you have permission to write/read in this folder with this account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the other files are on a different machine, here is one possiblity: https://serverfault.com/questions/41130/network-service-account-accessing-a-folder-share

Another possiblity is to impersonate a domain account that has access to the target folder- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

Or change the service account to a domain account that has access to the target folder.

Comment: We can't do impersonation in general, since this is a very large preexisting commerce website...the testing for a global change would be prohibitive.  But it does make me think that I might be able to just drop this functionality into it's own directory, and put a local web.config in that directory, and do impersonation there.  (I can't try this right now unfortunately...but when I can, I'll report on results.)  I'll also look at your first option when I can (probably early tomorrow.)  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the options. The 2nd option was what worked for me (impersonating a user, specifically created for this access, and putting that into a web.config in a directory with only that file), but the other options sound like good options that might work for other people with a similar issue.